# Using database functions to transform columns in hibernate criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

Despite 3 hours of googling and searching the API I can't find any reference to whether it's possible to use database functions within a hibernate criteria query.  To be specific:

I'd like to access the date portion of the datetime in a postgres database and group by that. I'd imagine the query would look something like:

```
session.createCriteria(Exam.class)
  .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
    .add(Projections.property("DATE(beginExam)").as("beginDate"))
    .add(Projections.groupProperty("beginDate")))
  .list();
```

This does not work giving me a "could not resolve property: Date(beginExam)..." exception.  It seems like this is a very simple thing to do, and I must be missing something.  Given that I am also building restrictions dynamically (I've left that out in the example) it seems that criteria is the hibernate component to use for this, but I'm open to any suggestions at this point short of side stepping the whole issue by building my own group by.

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Have you tried [Projections.sqlProjection](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/index.html?org/hibernate/Criteria.html) like this

```
session.createCriteria(Exam.class)
  .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
  .add(Projections.sqlProjection("date(beginExam) as beginDate", new String[] { "beginDate" }, new Type[] { StandardBasicTypes.DATE }))
  .add(Projections.groupProperty("beginDate")))
.list();
```

or Projections.sqlGroupProjection like this

```
session.createCriteria(Exam.class)
  .setProjection(Projections.sqlGroupProjection("date(beginExam) as beginDate", "beginDate", new String[] { "beginDate" }, new Type[] { StandardBasicTypes.DATE }))
.list();
```

Hibernate generates table aliases in SQL queries, so you may need to add the `{alias}` fragment to your SQL fragment to make this work:

```
session.createCriteria(Exam.class)
  .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
  .add(Projections.sqlProjection("date({alias}.beginExam) as beginDate", new String[] { "beginDate" }, new Type[] { StandardBasicTypes.DATE }))
  .add(Projections.groupProperty("beginDate")))
.list();
```

or with `SQLGroupProjection`:

```
session.createCriteria(Exam.class)
  .setProjection(Projections.sqlGroupProjection("date({alias}.beginExam) as beginDate", "beginDate", new String[] { "beginDate" }, new Type[] { StandardBasicTypes.DATE }))
.list();
```

Comment: @user996088: Note my edit regarding the `{alias}` fragment, did my suggested solution work out? I'm kinda curious because I didn't actually execute one of the queries, I just wrote them here (so there might as well be typos)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Projections.sqlProjection](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Projections.html#sqlProjection%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20org.hibernate.type.Type%5B%5D%29) and Porjections.sqlGroupProjection

Comment: I did, thoroughly. Amongst the many methods for eq and between there is no method to transform the value of the column to a date so it can then be compared or put in a groupProperty.

Comment: @user996088: What's the data type of beginExam? you can use _any_ SQL in Projections.sqlProjection so I don't see why you shouldn't be able to convert it to a date.

Comment: My fault. In my angst I didn't recognize that gkamal had pointed me in the right direction with the wrong link.

Comment: fixed the link - issue with java doc with frames.  I was on the correct page - copied the wrong link form the address bar.